# Программа не получает значения определённых полей из БД на Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-database, firebase-android

Я написал программу, которая получает данные из БД на `firebase` и выводит их в логи в виде: `ключ-запрашиваемое значение`. Её код выглядит вот так:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private DatabaseReference mDatabase;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl("https://fireapp-12b506.firebaseio.com/users");


        ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot userSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Log.d("BD",userSnapshot.getKey()+": "+userSnapshot.getValue(User.class).getEmail());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });


    }
```

Вышеописанный код работает нормально:

```
    05-15 17:40:36.629 19979-19979/com.example.max.fireapp D/BD: mBeHJEcNPOaedpIOamfNoKHhhGakJePeo: пользователь 46768
05-15 17:40:36.629 19979-19979/com.example.max.fireapp D/BD: mFLKEoDimJNIjkIBhdeJpMLDgLfeAcejo: пользователь 14523
05-15 17:40:36.629 19979-19979/com.example.max.fireapp D/BD: mMneiibECnGpLoLlDfNkkbACfFkmjgBoC: пользователь 17554
05-15 17:40:36.630 19979-19979/com.example.max.fireapp D/BD: mOEphdnALeEMDOOFofjHkGbfGNeIdhGLI: пользователь 89576
05-15 17:40:36.631 19979-19979/com.example.max.fireapp D/BD: mdPGcMNCanmPIgEAGKfpflcAiAfCfHDOF: пользователь 72895
05-15 17:40:36.631 19979-19979/com.example.max.fireapp D/BD: mnaPbkBfmOKgePHHDNLeDkPHdeCMiAJKb: пользователь 84574
```

Но стоит мне заменить строчку из цикла на(`getUsername()` заменён на `getEmail()`):

```
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
 for (DataSnapshot userSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
     Log.d("BD",userSnapshot.getKey()+": "+userSnapshot.getValue(User.class).getEmail());
   }
 }
```

, то код перестаёт корректно работать:

```
05-15 17:44:41.973 20233-20233/com.example.max.fireapp D/BD: mBeHJEcNPOaedpIOamfNoKHhhGakJePeo: null
05-15 17:44:41.973 20233-20233/com.example.max.fireapp D/BD: mFLKEoDimJNIjkIBhdeJpMLDgLfeAcejo: null
05-15 17:44:41.974 20233-20233/com.example.max.fireapp D/BD: mMneiibECnGpLoLlDfNkkbACfFkmjgBoC: null
05-15 17:44:41.974 20233-20233/com.example.max.fireapp D/BD: mOEphdnALeEMDOOFofjHkGbfGNeIdhGLI: null
05-15 17:44:41.975 20233-20233/com.example.max.fireapp D/BD: mdPGcMNCanmPIgEAGKfpflcAiAfCfHDOF: null
05-15 17:44:41.975 20233-20233/com.example.max.fireapp D/BD: mnaPbkBfmOKgePHHDNLeDkPHdeCMiAJKb: null
```

Как это исправить? В базу данных записаны экземпляры класса `User`:

```
public class User {
    private String Username;
    private String Email;

    public User(){

    }

    public User(String username, String email) {
        this.Username = username;
        this.Email = email;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return Username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        Username = username;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return Email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.Email = email;
    }
}
```

, а сама БД выглядит так:
[Организация базы данных](https://sun9-5.userapi.com/c840526/v840526958/82852/FEIJenZvU1s.jpg).

Comment: Полагаю что из-за несовпадения имён полей в классе `User` с именами в базе. В таких случаях, насколько я понял нужно использовать аннотации `@PropertyName("имя_в_базе")`

Comment: как вариант, вы можете сравнить переименовать поля в базе. Они у вас должны быть соотвествтенно username и email. P/S небольшое замечание: определите имена переменных с маленьких букв - это не классы (не соотвествует code style)